# beginbegin cannot be detected

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have issue with a value that should have just work, however, it seem to be a bug which I could not understand. Maybe you can find any bug?

Note: I have no issue with the "begin" and "end", just "beginbegin" and "endend" always return false.

My array values:

```
beginbegin,endend,-,-,-,begin,end,-,-,-,begin,end,-,-,-,-,begin,-,end
```

My code:

```
private var xm:int = 0;

            private function createBeam():void {
                for(var a:int=xm;a<naArray.length;a++) {
                    if(beamStatusArray[a]=="begin" || beamStatusArray[a]=="beginbegin") {
                        xm = a;
        trace(beamStatusArray[a]=="beginbegin");  //always return false even there a "beginbegin" in the array
    if(beamStatusArray[a]=="begin" || beamStatusArray[a]=="beginbegin") {
                var getBeam:int = yArray[a]
                for(var aa:int=a;aa<naArray.length;aa++) {
                    if(beamStatusArray[aa]=="end" || beamStatusArray[aa]=="endend") {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you getting the variable aa for the outer for loop (var a:int=aa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like it's with your loop code and not the string comparison. Why is the counter in the outer loop initialized to `aa` instead of 0?

Comment: it is correct to use aa instead of start from 0, so that I can return the last index and continue loop until the end of the array.

Comment: Where is aa declared and what value does it have at the beginning of createBeam? If it is a class variable it's generally not a good idea to declare another variable with the same name in the inner loop.

Comment: now update my code, I still get "beginbegin" false with my new code. Or what do you suggest?

Comment: There must be something else you're missing. Try setting a breakpoint on the trace and making sure that your array values are what you expect.

Comment: Solve: I found a solution! Adding String(xmlstring...) cast so that it will become a String legally, it seem to be a bug with E4X where when there are 2 xml elements with the value of "begin" which to me seem to be concat by accident (no concat code was used in my code), it would become abnormal?